# "promise already under evaluation" error in R caret's rfe function

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I have a matrix `X` and vector `Y` which I use as arguments into the `rfe` function from the `caret` package. It's as simple as:

I get a weird error which I can't decipher:

> promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

EDIT:
Here is a reproducible example for the first 5 rows of my data:

```
library(caret)

X_values = c(29.04,96.57,4.57,94.23,66.81,26.71,69.01,77.06,49.52,97.59,47.57,64.07,24.25,11.27,77.30,90.99,44.05,30.96,96.32,16.04)
X = matrix(X_values, nrow = 5, ncol=4)
Y = c(5608.11,2916.61,5093.05,3949.35,2482.52)

rfe(X, Y)
```

My R version is 3.2.3. Caret package is 6.0-76.

Does anybody know what this is?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would appreciate if you would remove bad rates for my question after the edit, or elaborate why you have left them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You need to specify the function/algorithm that you want to fit. (this is what causes the error message you get. I am unsure why `rfe` throws such a cryptic error message; it makes it difficult to debug, indeed.)
2. You need to name your columns in the input data.

The following works:

```
library(caret)

X_values = c(29.04,96.57,4.57,94.23,66.81,26.71,69.01,77.06,49.52,97.59,47.57,64.07,24.25,11.27,77.30,90.99,44.05,30.96,96.32,16.04)
X = matrix(X_values, nrow = 5, ncol=4)
Y = c(5608.11,2916.61,5093.05,3949.35,2482.52)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs)
colnames(X) <- letters[1:ncol(X)]

set.seed(123)
rfe(X, Y, rfeControl = ctrl)
```

I chose a linear model for the rfe. 
The reason for the warning messages is the low number of observations in your data during cross validation. You probably also want to set the `sizes` argument to get a meaningful feature elimination.

Comment: I get the same error if I try to call `rfe(X, Y, ctrl)` rather than `rfe(X, Y, rfeControl=ctrl)`